# I'm trying to open my app on a specific page using deeplinking but it keeps opening the start page

Tags: android, deep-linking

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data android:scheme="deeplinkingtest"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".resetresponse">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="callum.pixelpin.co.uk"
                    android:pathPrefix="/ResetRequest" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="pixelpin.co.uk"
                    android:pathPrefix="/SignIn/ResetRequest" />
                <data android:scheme="deeplinkingtest"
                    android:host="resetresponse"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I think it may have to do with the scheme, host and pathPrefix not being correct.

The URL in which the app is checking is as follows:

> https://login.pixelpin.co.uk/SignIn/ResetResponse.aspx

Full URL:

> https://login.pixelpin.co.uk/SignIn/ResetResponse.aspx?code=OAWIBGOAWO893745OBFAIN&user=4389246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Deeplink class set Like below code and must be remove other All scheme .


    <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data android:scheme="your scheme" />
                </intent-filter>

Include the BROWSABLE category. The BROWSABLE category is required in order for the intent filter to be accessible from a web browser. Without it, clicking a link in a browser cannot resolve to your app. The DEFAULT category is optional, but recommended. Without this category, the activity can be started only with an explicit intent, using your app component name.
```

Comment: No Luck, still opens the launch page

Comment: what is your package name of app ?

Comment: just put on scheme and other scheme are remove from this activity.

Comment: remove scheme from resetresponse class
 <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="callum.pixelpin.co.uk"
                    android:pathPrefix="/ResetRequest" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="pixelpin.co.uk"
                    android:pathPrefix="/SignIn/ResetRequest" />

Comment: Just a correction, in the .MainActivity you will need to add "<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>" or otherwise the app wouldn't launch, can you make the edit then i'll mark your answer as correct